# Does $(x,f(x),\cdots,f^p(x))$ is linearly dependent over $E$ implies $(id, f, ..., f ^ p)$ is linearly dependent over $\mathcal{L}(E)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Here is the original (classic I think) problem I had encored:

> if $(x,f(x))$ is a linearly dependent family of $E$ (a vector space) for all $x\in E$, then the family $(id,f)$ is linearly dependentt over $\mathcal{L}(E)$.

Naturally I am tempted now to generalize this exercise.

Let $E$ be a finite dimensional vector space of $\Bbb{C}$ and $f$ an element of $\mathcal{L}(E)$ has the following property: there is a natural nonzero integer $p$ such that $(x,f(x),\cdots,f^p(x))$ is linearly dependent over $E$ for all $x\in E$. I

*Question*: Is it true that the family $(id, f, ..., f ^ p)$ is linearly dependentover $\mathcal{L}(E)$?

I think the answer is $Yes$, I would say something like that.

There is a vector $x$ such that the minimum polynomial $f$ is the generator of the ideal $$\{P :\quad P (f) (x) = 0\}$$

> Is it correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is YES. Let $M$ be the minimal polynomial of $f$. Over 
$\mathbb C$ we can factorize $M$ as $\prod_{k=1}^{r} (X-\lambda_k)^{a_k}$
with $\lambda_k\in{\mathbb C}, a_k\geq 1$ and $\lambda_i\neq \lambda_j$
if $i\neq j$. By the kernel decomposition theorem, we have the direct decomposition

$$E=\bigoplus_{k=1}^r E_k\tag{1}$$

where $E_k={\sf Ker}(f-\lambda_k{\sf Id}_E)^{a_k}$.

Note that $(f-\lambda_k{\sf Id}_E)^{a_k-1}$ cannot be zero on $E_k$, because otherwise
$\frac{M}{X-\lambda_k}$ would annihilate $f$, contradicting the definition
on $M$. So there is an $x_k\in E_k$ such that $(f-\lambda_k{\sf Id}_E)^{a_k-1} (x_k) \neq 0$.  Let $x=\sum_{k=1}^r x_k$. For any polynomial $P$, we have the direct decomposition
$P(f)x=\sum_{k=1}^r P(f)x_k$, so that $P(f)x$ is zero iff each $P(f)x_k$ is individually
zero. It follows that $P(f)x=0$ iff $P$ is a multiple of $M$. So $p$ is larger
than the degree of $M$, and we are done.

Answer (score 1):

This is a theorem of Aupetit. For a proof see [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=fuONq1od6nsC&pg=PA46&lpg=PA46&dq=aupetit%201988%20linear%20independence&source=bl&ots=l51aRTzLVT&sig=_VQkp5PLGukjT42vvtqH-oJ-rL4&hl=en&sa=X&ei=gwojVMysMsucygTXyICICQ&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=aupetit%201988%20linear%20independence&f=false).